# error writing from csv to mysql using pentaho pdi

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pdi

I am a newbee to pentaho.
Is there any reason why I am having this error as try to write csv content to mysql using dataset from the link below:
   "Unknown Latitude' in field list.

I am using dataset from link below:
   http://openflights.org/data.html
I have 3 steps:
- "csv file input" which previews fine
- "select values" which also previews fine
- a "table output" where the proble lies.

regards

[image]

Comment: What is the problem, what error do you get? Seems like you are trying to insert more columns than you have in your table.

Comment: What is the Select Values step doing?  Depending on how it's configured, that could well be the source of the error.